# How to pass often used ("global") variables in ES-6 modules?

Tags: javascript, architecture, es6-modules

I can't create arhitecture for js-code for site.

There are 2 versions of site: mobile and desktop. I want to build separate js-bundle for every version: **mobile.js** and **desktop.js**.
Every bundle can include common js-modules, for example **form.js** (form exists on every site version). But there some uniq elements: desktop has Header and need **header.js**, mobile has no Header, but has Topbar and need **topbar.js**.
Bundle for mobile (mobile.js) includes form.js + header.js
Bundle for desktop (desktop.js) includes form.js + topbar.js

Imagine that we need to show form when click on Header(or Topbar).

```
Our folder structure:
--common/
----form.js
--desktop/
----header.js
--mobile/
----topbar.js
--entryDesktop.js
--entryMobile.js
```

.

```
//--- entryDesktop.js
import Form from './common/form.js';
import Header from './desktop/header.js';

new Form(document.querySelector('.form'));
new Header(document.querySelector('.header'));
```

.

```
//--- entryMobile.js
import Form from './common/form.js';
import Header from './mobile/topbar.js';

new Form(document.querySelector('.form'));
new Header(document.querySelector('.header'));
```

.

```
//--- form.js
export default class Form{
  constructor(elem) {
    this.elem = elem;
  }

  show() {
    this.elem.classList.remove('form_hidden');
  }
}
```

Actually, modules header.js and topbar.js are very different, have different properties and methods, BUT they have one common action - they can open Form when click on Header (or Topbar)

```
export default class Header{
  constructor(elem) {
    this.elem = elem;
    ...
    this.elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
      form.show(); 
    })
  }
}
```

.

```
export default class Topbar{
  constructor(elem) {
    this.elem = elem;
    ...
    this.elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
      form.show(); 
    })
  }
}
```

**The main question is how to pass "form" in Header-module (and Topbar-module)?**

I can imagine 2 variants

1. Through window global object.

   ````
   window.form = new Form(document.querySelector('.form'));```

   ```//---topbar.js:
   this.elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
     window.form.show(); 
   })```
   ````

BUT then our variables are not isolated, we or third-party scripts can change it occasionally.

2. Pass "form" as parametr in Class

   ````
   const form = new Form(document.querySelector('.form'))
   new Header(document.querySelector('.topbar'), form);```

   ```//---header.js:
   export default class Header{
     constructor(elem, form) {
       this.elem = elem;
       this.form = form;
       this.elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
         this.form.show(); 
       })
     }
   }```
   ````

BUT if i need Form in 20 modules - i should pass it in every.
If 1st module imports 2nd module that imports 3d module, and I need Form in 3d module - I need to pass it through All this modules. It looks like hell. Or not?

What is the best way to pass often used variables in specific module?

Comment: U can use global just do GLOBAL_VAR = value

Comment: Yes, thanks, i know I just use "window.my_var" to clarify my thought